# How to find the gameID of a roblox place within a game?

Tags: lua, roblox

I want to teleport a player from one place in my game, the lobby place, to another place in the game, but the TeleportService uses the GameId, and I cannot find the game ID. The Roblox Wiki says you can find it in the Game Explorer, but that has been deprecated. How can I find the GameID or is there an alternate way to teleport players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TeleportService:Teleport(placeId, player)](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/TeleportService/Teleport) function uses PlaceIds, not GameIds to teleport players. Once you publish your game, you can find the PlaceIds for it in a few places.

**In Lua :**

The [DataModel.PlaceId](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/DataModel/PlaceId) property holds the current published place's Id, and you can access it from the global `game` object.

```
local placeId = game.PlaceId
```

**In Roblox Studio :**

1. Open the place in Studio.
2. From the View tab, open the Asset Manager.
3. In the Asset Manager, double click on the Places. It should bring up a list of all of the Places for your game.
4. Right click on one of the places
5. Select `Copy Id to Clipboard`.
6. Paste the Id where you need it.

[image: A picture of the Asset Manager widget in Roblox Studio. A place has been right clicked and a context menu has appeared. The option Copy ID to Clipboard is highlighted.]

---

**On the Roblox website :**

1. From the [Create page](https://www.roblox.com/develop), go to `My Creations`.
2. In the left hand tab menu, select Places.
   [image: An image of the Creations dashboard on the roblox website. Under the Your Creations section, the Places tab is highlighted. A single game is visible.]
3. Find your place and click on it. It will take you to a page where you can click the Play button and hop into that place.
4. Observe the URL for that page. It should be something like : `https://www.roblox.com/games/<some_number>/<some_name>`
5. Copy the number out of the url. You now have the placeId.
6. Paste the Id where you need it.

[image: An image of the web page that launches the roblox game. There is a red circle around the URL of the page to highlight the number inside it.]

Answer (score 0):

The game id is in the top right corner of roblox studio. It should be there.

Comment: Where exactly in the studio? I don't see it